# Blender 2.6: How to Undo 3D Cursor Movement

Tags: graphics, blender

I sometimes place the 3D cursor at the wrong location by a undesigned click on the left mouse button.

But when I'm trying to click `Control + Z` in order to undo the accidental 3D cursor movement, it doesn't revert.

So **my question** is: Is there an easy way to get Blender's (2.6) 3D cursor back to it's *previous location*? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editing tool state changes (including the cursor) are not placed on the undo stack. That's intended behavior. Some one [tried to file a bug](http://projects.blender.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=498&aid=31763&group_id=9) about it, not too long ago, and it was closed as intentional behavior.

You can brush up on cursor behavior [here](http://www.blenderjourney.com/2012/01/28/blender-beginner-tips-1-cursor-and-origin/).

If you really want to keep the cursor in one place, you can create an object at the position, hide it, then you'll have something to snap-to the position if you ever lose cursor placement.

Additionally, there are plugins that you might like. Specifically for this situation:

[Enhanced 3D Cursor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Enhanced_3D_Cursor)

Which provides:

- Cursor location history
- Cursor location bookmarks

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But isn't there any cleaner and simpler to do that? I mean creating hidden object as some kind of "3D point bookmark" all the time not kind of fun.

Comment: Is there another way to create something like a "marker" or a "bookmark" at some 3D point? th

Comment: See my edits for additional options.